# How to create a subdomain that points to a service on a port in Z-Admin?

Tags: linux

In Z-Admin I Would like to create a subdomain that points to a Service on the same domain but to a specific port.
Example:

I want glassfish.mydomain.com to point to mydomain.com:8080

How is possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're administrative panel has a DNS manager then you can do this by assigning where subdomain.domain.tld points by use of an A record.(For example)

If not, you'll want to setup a record with your current domain registrar to send requests for your subdomain to the subsequent address